# Importing an joining Parts of a Robot manipulator arm (6-Axis) and making each joint rotate by user input(C++ code)

Tags: c++, qt5, blender, robotics, qt3d

I am trying to import 6 3D Meshes of joints of a Robot manipulator arm in Qt C++. The joints are being displayed, but they are not rotating as if they are connected together. But Each joint rotates independently around its own centre. I want to rotate each joint by c++ code and the other joints should also rotate. I am using Blender to set the centre of the meshes and exporting to obj file.

```
Qt3DCore::QEntity *root = new Qt3DCore::QEntity();
Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow view;

Joint *joint1 = new Joint(root);
joint1->mesh()->setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/assets/base.obj")));
joint1->transform()->setTranslation(QVector3D(0.0f, 1.81f, 0.0f));
joint1->transform()->setScale(0.01f);
Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial *material1 = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial();
material1->setDiffuse(QColor(204, 91, 70));
material1->setSpecular(QColor(255, 171, 247 ));
material1->setShininess(500.0f);
joint1->addComponent(material1);


Joint *joint2 = new Joint(root);
joint2->mesh()->setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/assets/j2.obj")));
joint2->transform()->setTranslation(QVector3D(0.0f, 1.9030f, 0.0f));
joint2->transform()->setScale(0.01f);
Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial *material2 = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial();
material2->setDiffuse(QColor(27, 176, 204));
material2->setSpecular(QColor(37, 95, 255 ));
material2->setShininess(500.0f);
joint2->addComponent(material2);

/*
 * Rest of the 4 joint meshes are defined in same way as above
 */

view.setRootEntity(root);
```

My Joint Class is as follows: 
joint.cpp

```
 #include "joint.h"

Joint::Joint(Qt3DCore::QNode *parent)
  : Qt3DCore::QEntity(parent)
  ,m_mesh(new Qt3DRender::QMesh())
  ,m_transform(new Qt3DCore::QTransform())
{
addComponent(m_mesh);
addComponent(m_transform);
}

Joint::~Joint()
{
}

Qt3DRender::QMesh *Joint::mesh() const
{
return m_mesh;
}

Qt3DCore::QTransform *Joint::transform() const
{
return m_transform;
}
```

My Joint header file:
joint.h

```
#ifndef JOINT_H
#define JOINT_H

#include <Qt3DCore/QEntity>

#include <Qt3DCore/QTransform>

#include <Qt3DRender/QMesh>


class Joint : public Qt3DCore::QEntity

{

public:
Joint(Qt3DCore::QNode *parent= 0);
~Joint();

Qt3DRender::QMesh *mesh() const;
 Qt3DCore::QTransform *transform() const;




private:
Qt3DRender::QMesh *m_mesh;
Qt3DCore::QTransform *m_transform;


};


#endif //JOINT_H
```

Comment: Sounds like your not parenting the bones to each other, when you rotate bone1, bone2 should move to stay connected to the end of it as well as rotate as desired. The steps would be - rotate the first bone, then move the second bone to the position of the end of the first bone and then rotate the second bone as desired.

Answer (score 0):

If your joints have a "parent-child" hierarchy, you should indicate each parent as `Joint *joint2 = new Joint(joint1);`.

With that, when you rotate the parent, children will rotate too. But it's not reciprocal (it works as parenting in Blender) : rotating or translating the child will not affect any of its parents.

Comment: Yes, I tried doing that, only ```joint1``` was being displayed while the rest joints were not being displayed on the screen.

Comment: @Rhnbmpl sounds like your are mixing up the coordinate systems. Have you made sure your translation of joint2 is relative to joint1? You have to make sure this is the case when you parent the two together like that - otherwise the final translation of joint2 will be the local translation of joint1 + the local translation of joint2.